# What is a "second-person singular future active indicative" verb?

Tags: verbs, conjugation

Does it means a verb that should be used with a subject that is second-person and singular? What does "future active indicative" mean?

For example, I know "[acuēs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acues)" roughly means "sharpen", but what's the right context? Does it means "(would like to) sharpen (you in the future)"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to the site!

Each of the adjectives you list tells you a little more about how the verb is being used.

**Second person** specifies **person**; it tells you that the subject of the verb is "you." If the subject were "I" or "we" the verb would be "first person" (*acuam* or *acuémus*), and if the subject were "she" or "he" or "they" it would be "third person" (*acuet* or *acuent*).

**Singular** specifies **number**; it tells you that the subject is one person ("you, Kay, and nobody else"). If the subject were "you, Kay, and your brother, Englebert," then the verb would be "plural" (*acuētis*).

**Future** specifies **tense**; it tells you that the action hasn't happened yet. If you were talking about sharpening something yesterday, the verb might be "perfect" (*acuistī*) or "imperfect" (*acuēbās*) or "pluperfect" (*acuerās*) depending on other things about what you wanted to say). If you were talking about something you were doing right now, the verb would be "present" (*acuis*).

**Active** specifies **voice**; it tells you that the subject is doing the verb rather than that the subject is having the verb done to him/her/it. If you were talking to a pencil, you might use a "passive" verb instead (*acueris*): "Pencil, you're going to be sharpened."

**Indicative** specifies **mood**, but it's a little tricky; it basically tells you that you're talking about something that's happening in reality as opposed to something that might happen or might have happened, in which case you'd use the "subjunctive" (*acuās, acuerēs, acueris*, or *acuissēs*), or something that you're ordering somebody to do, in which case you'd use the "imperative" (*acue* or *acuitō*). That's an oversimplification, but it's probably close enough for government work. (Note that there's no such thing as a future subjunctive, and the future imperative is pretty rare.)

Comment: I guess that wrapped it up pretty clearly. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I'm so very glad!

Comment: Latin digests a lot better if you know how to parse words in a sentence.  For substantives (i.e., nouns, pronouns,and adjectives), number and case give important clues on the function of a word in a sentence.  For verbs, number, voice, tense, and mood are key indicators.